# Pulseaudio and Jack: cant start jack on pop!os

Tags: jack

I am running an application that needs jack, so obviously I install jack! However when trying to start jack with qjackctl I get a huge running list of errors:

```
12:30:04.152 Statistics reset.
12:30:04.156 ALSA connection change.
12:30:04.158 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
12:30:04.182 ALSA connection graph change.
12:30:05.601 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:device', 'hw:0'): Invalid container address 'driver':'device':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Tue Mar 13 12:30:05 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'device':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
12:30:06.812 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:nperiods', '2'): Invalid container address 'driver':'nperiods':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
12:30:07.145 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:softmode', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'softmode':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:06 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'nperiods':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Mar 13 12:30:07 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'softmode':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Mar 13 12:30:08 2018: Saving settings to "/home/alex/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
12:30:09.210 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:shorts', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'shorts':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
12:30:09.993 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:hwmon', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'hwmon':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:09 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'shorts':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Mar 13 12:30:09 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'hwmon':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
12:30:10.175 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:hwmeter', 'false'): Invalid container address 'driver':'hwmeter':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
12:30:11.058 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:midi-driver'): Invalid container address 'driver':'midi-driver':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:10 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'hwmeter':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
Tue Mar 13 12:30:10 2018: Saving settings to "/home/alex/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
Tue Mar 13 12:30:11 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'midi-driver':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
12:30:11.872 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:duplex', 'true'): Invalid container address 'driver':'duplex':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:11 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'duplex':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
12:30:12.339 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:capture', 'hw:0'): Parameter value type mismatch: was expecting 'u', got 's'. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
12:30:12.807 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:playback', 'hw:0'): Parameter value type mismatch: was expecting 'u', got 's'. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:12 2018: ERROR: Parameter value type mismatch: was expecting 'u', got 's'
Tue Mar 13 12:30:12 2018: ERROR: Parameter value type mismatch: was expecting 'u', got 's'
12:30:13.290 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:inchannels'): Invalid container address 'driver':'inchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
12:30:13.940 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:outchannels'): Invalid container address 'driver':'outchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:13 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'inchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
Tue Mar 13 12:30:13 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'outchannels':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
12:30:14.406 D-BUS: SetParameterValue('driver:dither', 'n'): Invalid container address 'driver':'dither':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:14 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'dither':'(null)' supplied to method 'SetParameterValue'.
12:30:15.189 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:input-latency'): Invalid container address 'driver':'input-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
12:30:15.670 D-BUS: ResetParameterValue('driver:output-latency'): Invalid container address 'driver':'output-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.. (org.jackaudio.Error.InvalidArgs)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:15 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'input-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
Tue Mar 13 12:30:15 2018: ERROR: Invalid container address 'driver':'output-latency':'(null)' supplied to method 'ResetParameterValue'.
12:30:16.741 D-BUS: JACK server is starting...
12:30:16.742 D-BUS: JACK server was started (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: Starting jack server...
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: ERROR: Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: ERROR: AcquireSelfRealTime error
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_1'
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: New client 'system' with PID 0
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_2'
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_1'
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_2'
12:30:18.859 JACK connection change.
12:30:18.860 Server configuration saved to "/home/alex/.jackdrc".
12:30:18.861 Statistics reset.
12:30:18.877 Client activated.
12:30:18.878 Patchbay deactivated.
12:30:18.926 JACK connection graph change.
Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:18 2018: New client 'qjackctl' with PID 2852
```

A little bit of research on this topic shows that this may be down to the fact that I am also running pulseaudio, which doesnt allways play nice with Jack. I have tried 10/15 different fixes (stopping the pulseaudio daemon etx) but still get the same list of errors

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that jackd can not start, due to a common problem:

```
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Mar 13 12:30:16 2018: ERROR: Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
```

You are not a member of the audio group, so:

```
usermod -a -G audio yourusername
```

then restart. The jack-dbus warnings will continue, but jackd will start.

Now, if you have the pulseaudio-jack package installed, you can load the jack-sink to route pulseaudio to jack:

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink
```